# How to call the swagger page after containerizing a .NET 7 app using the .NET 7 SDK?

Tags: docker, .net-7.0

I am a .NET developer but I am new to .NET 7. .NET 7 enables developers to containerize applications without creating dockerfile as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/docker/publish-as-container?source=recommendations). However, so far I did not succeed in calling the swagger page after containerization using the .NET 7 SDK features for that.

Here are the steps to reproduce:

1. Create the web api

```
dotnet new webapi --no-https
```

2. Change the csproj

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <UserSecretsId>dotnet-DotNet.ContainerImage-2e40c179-a00b-4cc9-9785-54266210b7eb</UserSecretsId>
     <ContainerImageName>dotnet-worker-image</ContainerImageName>
     <ContainerImageTag>1.2.3-alpha2</ContainerImageTag>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ContainerPort Include="80" Type="tcp" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.OpenApi" Version="7.0.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Build.Containers" Version="7.0.306" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.5.0" />
    
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

3. Build the image.

```bash
dotnet publish --os linux --arch x64 /t:PublishContainer -c Release
```

3. Check and copy the Image ID of the newly created docker image (using the docker UI)
4. Run container based on that image

```
docker run --rm -it -p 5999:80 f14ea411b07b21adfdf7cfb80e910dcf63577c2e578f6a1c23d7825f35b51752
```

5. Open a http file in VS Code (with [this extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=humao.rest-client) installed) and call:

```http
GET http://localhost:5999/swagger/index.html
```

Suprisingly, I get a 404 while a 200 is expected. How come? And how to fix this? Calling the application itself succeeds as the response header mentions Kestrel.

```http
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Content-Length: 0
Connection: close
Date: Tue, 25 Jul 2023 12:53:30 GMT
Server: Kestrel
```

However, it's a 404 where a 200 is expected so hopefully someone can help me with this.

Comment: #1 Did it worked in your localhost? #2 Enter to the container and execute this : `http://localhost/swagger/index.html`. Share us the result

Comment: It did work in localhost when not using docker? However, I want to use docker.

Comment: We all use docker. I have dozens of different netcore 7 apps with docker deployed in some cloud. Swagger works fine. #1 What about the curl test? #2 Share us a hello world code (github)reproducing your issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Swagger is only available when your program runs in a development environment. A container is not, by default, considered a development environment, so Swagger isn't available.

The code that sets up Swagger is in your Program.cs file and looks like this

```
// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}
```

To set your container to be a development environment, you need to set the environment variable `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` to `Development`.

You can do that on your `docker run` command, like this

```
docker run --rm -it -e ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development -p 5999:80 f14ea411b07b21adfdf7cfb80e910dcf63577c2e578f6a1c23d7825f35b51752
```

Other options are to set the environment variable permanently using an `ENV` statement in your Dockerfile.

Or you can change your program to always make Swagger available, no matter what environment it runs in. You do that by removing the `if` statement in Program.cs so `UseSwagger` and `UseSwaggerUI` are always called.

Which option is right for you depends a bit on how you want your application to behave in production. Most people don't like exposing Swagger to the general public which is why disabling it in non-development environments is the default.